How to encode a function from an existential type
I am having trouble using parametricity to show that existential types work in System F (or System Fω) in the way one would expect them to work.
It is known that an existential type $\exists t.~P~t$ (where $P$ is any type constructor, not necessarily covariant) is encoded as:  $$\forall r.~(\forall t.~P~t \to r)\to r $$
(I think it is assumed that $\forall r$ implies a parametricity constraint.)
Let's denote this encoding as the type constructor $E : (* \to *) \to *$ that takes any $P : * \to *$ and makes a new type $\exists t.~P~t$ out of $P$. (Here, the notation * means the kind of types.)
So, for any type constructor $P$ we define:
$$E~P = \forall r.~(\forall t.~P~t \to r)\to r $$
 E P = ∀(r : *) → (∀(t : *) → P t → r) → r

To create values of the type $E~P$, one uses the standard function pack defined as:
 pack : ∀(s : *) → P s → E P
 pack = λ(s : *) → λ(ps : P s) → λ(r : *) → λ(c : ∀(t : *) → P t → r) → c s ps

Now, the main question is:
How to write a function type $(\exists t.~P~t) \to q$, where $q$ is a fixed type.
There are two ways of writing that type:

Just use the encoding $ E~P$ as shown above, and write: $$ T_1=  E~P\to q  = (\forall r.~(\forall t.~P~t \to r)\to r)\to q $$

Squint at $(\exists t.~P~t) \to q$ and notice that it should be just a function $P~t \to q$ but universally quantified in $t$. So, we should have: $$ T_2 = \forall t.~(P~t \to q) $$


I want to prove that the types  $T_1$ and $T_2$ are equivalent, under appropriate parametricity assumptions.
I don't seem to be able to do that, though.
What I tried:

Write explicit code for functions $\mathrm{out} : T_1 \to T_2 $ and $\mathrm{in}:T_2\to T_1$ and then prove that in and out are inverses.
out : (E P → q) → ∀(t : *) → P t → q
out = λ(y : E P → q) → λ(t : *) → λ(pt : P t) → y (pack t pt)

in : (∀(t : *) → P t → q) → E P → q
in = λ(c : ∀(t : *) → P t → q) → λ(ep : E P) → ep q c



I can prove that out . in = id (this is just straightforward substitution).
The difficult direction is to prove that in . out = id; this requires some parametricity assumptions. I tried using the naturality law of $ E~P$ but that does not seem to be enough.
Specifically, after using the naturality law,  it still remains to prove that, for any $e : E~P$, that is, $e : \forall r.~(\forall t.~P~t \to r)\to r$, we will have: $$ e~ (E~ P)~ \mathrm{pack} = e  $$

The Yoneda identities do not apply because of the universal quantifier inside $\forall t. ~P~t\to r$.

I have read Wadler's "Recursive types for free" but the techniques in there don't seem to help so far. The identity e (E P) pack == e is superficially similar to the identity  (4) shown in Wadler: fold T in  =  id but the types are different and I can't prove what I need.



Using function extensionality, it suffices to prove:
$$∀ Z\ z. e\ (E\ P)\ \mathrm{pack}\ Z\ z = e\ Z\ z$$
The naturality rule for $e$ is:
$$f\ (e\ A\ k) = e\ B\ (ΛR. λr. f\ (k\ R\ r))$$
If we pick $k = \mathrm{pack}$, so $A = E\ P$, and $f\ e = e\ Z\ z$, then we get:
$$e\ (E\ P)\ \mathrm{pack}\ Z\ z = e\ Z\ (ΛR. λr. \mathrm{pack}\ R\ r\ Z\ z) = e\ Z\ (ΛR. λr. z\ R\ r) = e\ Z\ z$$
So that gets you the $e\ (E\ P)\ \mathrm{pack} = e$ equation you want.

Thank you, that looks perfect. I didn't think of writing out the extensional equality of functions like you did (with an arbitrary Z z). Without that, I could not find a suitable f for the naturality law. I will need to go through your derivation once again before approving the answer.
